# Cross compilation for gpsd shows "unrecognized option"

Tags: c++, c, gcc, scons, gpsd

I am cross-compiling gpsd3.20 on my Ubuntu 16.04 for the ARM architecture. As you may know, gpsd uses Sconsctruct to compile the source codes. During my cross-compilation, the moment when it needs to create the libgps.so it shows an error `unrecognized option '-Wl, -Bsymbolic'`.

Before posting the question here, I have tried t check my toolchain binaries and I found out that if I run this line manually:

```
sudo ./arm-v7a-linux-gnueabihf-ld -o test/gpsd-3.20/libgps.so.25.0.0 -pthread -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-soname=libgps.so.25 test/gpsd-3.20/os_compat.os test/gpsd-3.20/rtcm2_json.os test/rtcm3_json.os test/gpsd-3.20/shared_json.os test/gpsd-3.20/timespec_str.os test/gpsd-3.20/libgpsmm.os -L. -lrt -lm -lrt
```

The above commands print out the exact error as I mentioned previously. However, if I run the exact command replacing `ld` with `gcc`, then there is no any errors.

```
sudo ./arm-v7a-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o test/gpsd-3.20/libgps.so.25.0.0 -pthread -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-soname=libgps.so.25 test/gpsd-3.20/os_compat.os test/gpsd-3.20/rtcm2_json.os test/rtcm3_json.os test/gpsd-3.20/shared_json.os test/gpsd-3.20/timespec_str.os test/gpsd-3.20/libgpsmm.os -L. -lrt -lm -lrt
```

Upon checking the `arm-v7a-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` --help, I found out that, gcc support `-Wl`options whereas in the `arm-v7a-linux-gnueabihf-ld` it doesn't support the `-Wl` options. So now I am not sure how to change the SConstruct file so that it doesn't execute `ld` instead I want it to execute `gcc` especially for the libgps.so part.

Comment: Hi, to my knowledge, arm-v7a-linux-gnueabihf-ld is the linker, and arm-v7a-linux-gnueabihf-gcc is the compiler. Those are two different tools that serve two different purposes. 

For compilation, it seems more appropriate to use arm-v7a-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.

It seems that your issue is linked to some options. Have you checked the documentation for options to use with gcc : https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html ?

Comment: -Wl is a directive to pass whatever's after the comma to the linker subprocess. So if you pass it directly to a linker, it will fail. In that case you'd need to pass '-Bsymbolic" instead.

Answer (score 0):

(can't comment), so as answer: have you tried to set the env.-var.:
`export LD=arm-v7a-linux-gnuabihf-gcc`

Gcc takes `-Wl,XXX` and passes XXX to the linker.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got two combining problems here, though there's some guessing involved without looking into the build itself.  First, scons shouldn't be adding the flag when building a library (https://github.com/SCons/scons/issues/3248 - fixed but, I believe, not part of a release). Second, "linking" should probably be done using gcc.  If you call gcc to link, it still calls the linker behind the scenes - after dealing with options that are intended for gcc, which `-Wl,-Bsymbolic` is, it means pass `-Bsymbolic` on to the linking phase (indicated by `-Wl`, the 'l' meaning linker).  So I'm supposing that the way you've told scons about the cross toolchain isn't quite right either, if it's calling ld directly you're probably going to have other issues as well.